# Как заменить содержание полей drupal 7 с помощью php

Tags: php, drupal, rules

Есть модуль Conditional Rules в котором правило запускает php код. Код должен проверять наличие слова в описании материала и вписывать определённое слово в другое поле. Не знаю как обращаться к описанию и созданному полю. Буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Решил всё вот таким незамысловатым кодом:
$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 110; // новое значение поля описания
$node->field_region[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'] = 2; // новое значение поля термина таксономии
node_save($node);